# VB.Net Sql Server and MariaDB

Tags: sql, vb.net, mariadb

I'm Joinnes. I want to ask about query to count attempt when insert multiple data into MariaDB. I'm now developing API with Vb.Net code. I want to count 'attempt' when i insert data into MariaDB. in Sql I have AWB,Date,Time,Status,Recipient,Station,ReasonCode,ReasonNote field and in MariaDB i have ID,AWB,Tracking Number,Status,TimeStamp,Comment,Station,Recipient,Relation,ReasonCode,ReasonNote,Attempt,Username,RequestID,Flag field. The scenario is when i insert data into MariaDB how i count attempt if i have multiple same AWB according the status. so if there's three same Status insert with same AWB how to count each status and insert it into attempt column?

Note:
Status explain : OD=OnDelivery ; AR=Arrival ; UN=Undelivered ; OK=Success ; RT=Retur

If Status 'UN' greater then one with one AWB, how i count the 'attemmpt' using query and how to insert it into 'attemmpt' column in MariaDB?

Thanks before guys.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have populated the table?  Then something like this will do the counts:

```
SELECT AWB, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY AWB;

SELECT  AWB,
        Status,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY AWB, Status

SELECT  AWB,
        SUM(Status = 'UN')  AS 'count of UNs',
        COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY AWB
```

Don't insert the computed value into another column.  Instead recompute it when you need it.

Comment: Thank @Rick for your response but it's correctly yet.  I want is when I insert the data from my sqlDB into mariaDB my AWB have a few Status Likes AWB(123456789) the Status are PU(pickup),AR,OD,RT,UN,UN,UN,OK. It is a simple example for you. So, when I insert the data with a same 'Status' likes 'UN' I want to count the attempt of the 'UN' Status. if there's a three UN it will become 1.UN = First attempt, 2.UN = Second Attempt, 3.UN = Third attempt. I have populate the column named 'Attempt' so every count attempt I will insert there. how to that? Thanks a lot Rick :)

Comment: Sorry, I am still lost on the requirements.